# Is ROS.org the only place of information about ROS?

Tags: ros, beginner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are there other places?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9082/is-ros.org-the-only-place-of-information-about-ros?/) by [Alex Bravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/27/alex-bravo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 901 on 2011-02-15

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Good question, there really isn't that much out there. Someone should start a fansite! :)

The [Homebrew Robotics Club](http://hbrobotics.org/wiki/index.php?title=ROS_for_the_Rest_of_Us) seems to have some information about ROS. Looks like the [Pi Robot](http://www.pirobot.org/) does too (though most are external links).

---

Originally posted by [RobotGrrl](https://answers.ros.org/users/41/robotgrrl/) with karma: 141 on 2011-02-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Alex Bravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/27/alex-bravo/) on 2011-02-15**:
Pi Robot has a great site.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I know Trossen Robotics ROS forum is one such resource: [ROS - Robot Operating System](http://forums.trossenrobotics.com/forumdisplay.php?f=137)

---

Originally posted by [Alex Bravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/27/alex-bravo/) with karma: 901 on 2011-02-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1